# Finding the minimum value's key in an associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

In PHP, say that you have an associative array like this:

```
$pets = array(
    "cats" => 1,
    "dogs" => 2,
    "fish" => 3
);
```

**How would I find the key with the lowest value?** Here, I'd be looking for `cats`.

Is there some built in PHP function that I've missed which does this? It would also be great if there was a solution that accounted for several values being identical, as below:

```
$pets = array(
    "cats" => 1,
    "dogs" => 1,
    "fish" => 2
);
```

Above, I wouldn't mind if it just output either; `cats` or `dogs`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

[`array_keys`](http://docs.php.net/array_keys) is your friend:

```
$pets = array(
    "cats" => 1,
    "dogs" => 2,
    "fish" => 3
);
array_keys($pets, min($pets));  # array('cats')
```

**P.S.**: there is a dup here somewhere on SO (it had `max` instead of `min`, but I can distinctly remember it).

Comment: That's a clever one =) Maybe you should mention that it returns a list of 1 or more values (unless the array is empty.)

Comment: min(array_keys($pets, min($pets)); will ensure that you get ONE single answer, not an array.  That can be confusing to people who simply copy and paste this method.

Comment: @Augie Gardner current(array_keys($pets, min($pets)); - little bit faster

Comment: The above code is elegant but not optimal. It involves several operations (finding miniumum of N elements, find N keys, find the key with the value in a subset N). A faster version would be a search algorithm. I never did a benchmark about this, though.

Answer (score 14):

Thats how i did it.

```
$pets = array(
    "cats" => 1,
    "dogs" => 2,
    "fish" => 3
);

array_search(min($pets), $pets);
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Might try looking into these:

- [natcasesort(array)](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_natcasesort.asp)
- [natsort(array)](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_natsort.asp)

Comment: The links above are to the horrible w3schools, here are the proper PHP manual links (to save you a few seconds):
http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$min_val = null;
$min_key = null;
foreach($pets as $pet => $val) {
  if ($val < $min_val) {
    $min_val = $min;
    $min_key = $key;
  }
}
```

You can also flip the array and sort it by key:

```
$flipped = array_flip($pets);
ksort($flipped);
```

Then the first key is the minimum, and its value is the key in the original array.

Comment: You forgot to close a bracket.
And using array_keys and min, as suggested by SilentGhost will be easier and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for retrieving a single string is by using a [desirable sorting method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and retrieving the first key directly by using [`key()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) on the sorted array. In this instance the key with the lowest value is desired, `asort` will sort from lowest to highest values and reset the internal pointer. To retrieve the reverse (highest to lowest) use `arsort`.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/5ijPh

```php
$pets = array(
   "dogs" => 2,
   "cats" => 1,
   "fish" => 3
);
asort($pets);
var_dump(key($pets));
//string(4) "cats"
```

```php
$pets = array(
   "dogs" => 1,
   "cats" => 1,
   "fish" => 3
);
asort($pets);
var_dump(key($pets));
//string(4) "dogs"
```

---

Take note that all of the PHP array sorting methods will alter the array by-reference.
To prevent altering the original array, create a copy of the array or use an [`Iterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php).

```php
$petsSorted = $pets;
asort($petsSorted);
key($petsSorted);
```

Answer (score -3):

**find the highest value**

```
print max(120, 7, 8, 50);
```

*returns --> 120*

```
$array = array(100, 7, 8, 50, 155, 78);
print max($array);
```

*returns --> 155*

**find the lowest value**

```
print min(120, 7, 8, 50);
```

*returns --> 7*

```
$array = array(50, 7, 8, 101, 5, 78);
print min($array);
```

*returns --> 5*

Comment: The question is about finding the key, not just the value.