# Get min value in PHP array and get corresponding key

Tags: php, arrays, min

I have an array:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 0 )
```

I want PHP code that returns 1 because 1's value is the lowest.

How do I do this?

Comment: Dupe:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588353/finding-the-minimum-values-key-in-an-associative-array

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
array_keys($array, min($array));
```

Comment: It would be better if you write a little bit more, perhaps what you do and why. Maybe you can also link to an official documentation.

Comment: php.net's doc: "… If a `search_value` is specified, then only the keys for that value are returned …". An array containing "indexes" of matched items would be returned hence.

Answer (score 44):

This will return the first index that has the minimum value in the array. It is useful if you only need one index when the array has multiple instances of the minimum value:

```
$index = array_search(min($my_array), $my_array);
```

This will return an array of all the indexes that have the minimum value in the array. It is useful if you need all the instances of the minimum value but may be slightly less efficient than the solution above:

```
$indexes = array_keys($my_array, min($my_array));
```

Comment: This should be the acceppted answer, because Timothy Clemans asked about the array key.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

```
$array = array( [0] => 3, [1] => 0);
$min = min($array);
$index = array_search($min, $array);
```

Should return 1

Answer (score 1):

The below example would help you.

```
$values=array(3,0,4,2,1);
$min_value_key=array_keys($values, min($values));
echo $min_value_key;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code does not quite work because $min_value_key is an array, not a string.