# Get row with minimum mark php

Tags: php, arrays, min

I have a php array like below,

```
$array = array(
array(
 'mark' => 10,
 'name' => 'name 1',
),

array(
 'mark' => 15,
 'name' => 'name 2',
),
-------------------
-----------------
);
```

I need to get the row with minimum mark.

I can get the lowest mark as like bellow,

```
$numbers = array_map(function($array) {
return $details['mark'];
 }, $array);
$min = min($numbers);
```

But i don't know how to get the entire row.

Comment: The entire row? Maybe you search for the entire `array`, that's not a row?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude is it possible to get the details of student having lowest mark?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1588373/3647441

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['mark'] == $b['mark']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['mark'] < $b['mark']) ? -1 : 1;
});

$min = current($array);
$max = end($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to use so long codes when PHP already has what You need?
Use this one-liners. 
Compact (short), fast (because we collected columns at first), native (it's builtin):

```
$marks = array_column($array, 'mark'); // return "mark"s as array keeping keys of $array
$minimal_mark = min($marks); // gets minimal value
$minimal_mark_key = array_search($minimal_mark, marks); // searches for $minimal_mark value in $marks and returns array key
$minimal_mark_row = $array[$minimal_mark_key]; // gets element from array by key
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
$array = array(

array(
 'mark' => 10,
 'name' => 'name 1',
),

array(
 'mark' => 15,
 'name' => 'name 2',
)
);

$numbers = array_map(function($array) {
return $array['mark'];
 }, $array);

$min = min($numbers);
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code that's in the OP question