# Find min value in multidimensional array and return key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have read several similar questions on here, such as this, [Finding the minimum value's key in an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588353/finding-the-minimum-values-key-in-an-associative-array) but I think my problem may be unique in that my source array is not strings as keys.

My source array looks like this,

```
$dealers = array(
    array(
        [id] => 1526,
        [count] => 2
    ),
    array(
        [id] => 1518,
        [count] => 5
    ),
    array(
        [id] => 1511,
        [count] => 9
    ),
    array(
        [id] => 1410,
        [count] => 3
    )
);
```

I need to get the **id** of the smallest **count** value.

I have tried the following,

`$low_dealer = array_keys($dealers, min($dealers));`

But it appears to be returning the index of the lowest **id** and not count.

My next attempt was combining another function I found to find the min of the specific column,

`$low_dealer = array_keys($dealers, min( array_column( $dealers, 'count' ) ));`

But that returned nothing.

**EDIT:** Also must be able to handle multiple mins, if two or more have the same count number, need to get an array of them back so I can *rand()* it.

Would appreciate any tips here, thank you!

Comment: What if the lowest count is found in two or more rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dealersMin = min(array_column($dealers, 'count'));

$dealersWithMinCount = array_filter($dealers, function ($dealer) {
    global $dealersMin;
    return ($dealer['count'] == $dealersMin);
});

var_dump($dealersWithMinCount[array_rand($dealersWithMinCount)]['id']);
```

## [eval.in demo](https://eval.in/819623)

#### Explanation

1. First we find the lowest value of `'count'` in the array and save that to `$dealersMin`.
2. Then we need to get all rows in the `$dealers` array that have a count of `$dealersMin` and save that in `$dealersWithMinCount`.
3. Then just pick a random element of `$dealersWithMinCount` with [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: Added an edit to question, how can it handle if two or more have a min value?

Comment: Think Im following that thanks. Throwing me an undefined index though on the var_dump line...

Comment: @thatryan Oh, that's strange, is the `$dealers` array different to the one you posted in your question? I tried it in eval.in and it worked fine... Unless the `$dealers` array was empty, in which case you'd need to add checking before using the last line :)

Comment: Weird. No same array, just different variable name `$all_dealers` ( i just shortened it to post here ) and it is not empty because the `$dealersMin` get populated with 2, like it should.

Comment: No, I went to get lunch ha, back to debugging :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147213/discussion-between-thatryan-and-david).

Comment: Thanks for your help David. I got it to work by adding a global declaration to the initial variable as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
// indexed array: 2, 5, 9, 3
$counts = array_column($dealers, 'count');

// find index of min value
$index = array_search(min($counts), $counts, true);

// $dealers[$index]['id'];
```